# Print sequence number as 1-4 6-10 12-15

Tags: shell

I have a array in shell script as 4 5 6 7 9 10 14 15 16 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 27 28 29 30

i want to sort it and pass it to a variable output as 4-7 9-10 14-16 18-20  22-24 25 27-30

Not sure how to format it
tried for looping but did not work

Comment: What is the rule behind this pairing x-y? Why 4 5 6 7 becomes 4-7 but 9 10 becomes 9-10? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And include your attempted code in the question as well.

Comment: those are seq numbers and need to pair them as first and last seq number

Comment: What have you tried? How would _you_ do it? Do the same in shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
input_arr=(4 5 6 7 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 27 28 29 30)
output_arr=()
temp_arr=()
temp_arr+=(${input_arr[0]})
for ((i=0; i < ${#input_arr[@]}; i++)); do
    temp=$(expr ${input_arr[i]} + 1)
    [ "${input_arr[i+1]}" = "$temp" ] && temp_arr+=(${input_arr[i+1]})
    [ "${input_arr[i+1]}" != "$temp" ] && [ "${#temp_arr[@]}" -gt 1 ] && output_arr+=("${temp_arr[0]}-${temp_arr[-1]}") && temp_arr=() && temp_arr+=(${input_arr[i+1]})
done
echo "${output_arr[@]}"
```

Output:

```
4-7 9-10 12 14-16 18-20 22-25 27-30
```

Explanation:

- Loop over `input_arr` and keep a `temp_arr` (initialized with first element of `input_arr`) for sequential values.
- As soon as the sequence is broken, save current `temp_arr` start and
  end value to `output_arr` as `start-end` and reset `temp_arr` to start with the element
  that broke sequence (next `input_arr` array element)

Comment: Single numbers will be displayed wrong: `(32 34 36)` => ` 32-32 34-34 36-36`

Comment: With bash you can replace `temp=$(expr ${input_arr[i]} + 1)` with `((temp=input_arr[i]+1))`

Comment: @WalterA you are not OP, if OP asks for such requirements then I will update my answer. This is not a coding contest, SO answers should focus on what challenge OP is facing and not cater to edge cases suggested by on-lookers.

Comment: OP is not clear (he requested output `4-7 9-10 14-16 18-20 22-24 25 27-30`, where the isolated `25` is weird). First I thought my interpretation was logically, but you are right. OP can ask. His specifications are unclear. Thanks for answering both to OP and later to me.